# Getting undefined method errors with fresh ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, raspberry-pi

I've installed ruby on rails on my raspberry pi (following [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_Ruby_on_Rails) tutorial). I've created a new project and generated a controller with 3 actions. Thats all I did. When I run the server and navigate to one of the 3 actions, I always get this error:

```
NoMethodError in VolumeController#overview
undefined method `allow_forgery_protection' for nil:NilClass
```

I am new to ruby on rails but what I've already tried is to comment out the "protect_from_forgery with: :exception" line on my ApplicationController. But after doing so I get the following error on all actions:

```
NoMethodError in VolumeController#overview
undefined method `inheritable_copy' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand where this could come from. There is absolutely no code in the controllers and views yet, everything is still as it was generated by rails with the "rails g controller" command.

I then tried to generate a scaffold with rails in a new project and this works! But thats not what I want. I also tried to create my project and controller again but I still get the same error.

Is anybody out there who can help me? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 33):

I have the same error, and it was caused because i was defined a method call 'config'.
I change the name and it was solved. :)

Comment: This should be added as a comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: same here. It takes me a whole day to figure out :(

Comment: why? can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: @GoldChicken because we meet the [reserved words](http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/) in Rails. These words are being defined as methods, mixins, objects or classes so any overriding can be malfunctioned or break the ancestry chains. 
Solution 1. be specific 2. use a text editor with syntax highlighting

Comment: I'm so glad I found this answer! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just got burned by this with Rails 7, so it's still valid. In my case, it was during a controller test using minitest. The stack trace can be misleading and I had trouble understanding how the existing answer was relevant.

> Error: PostsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_post: NoMethodError:
> undefined method `allow_forgery_protection' for nil:NilClass
>
> def allow_forgery_protection; config.allow_forgery_protection; end
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PostsControllerTest>' test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:17:in` block in class:PostsControllerTest'

I was using a convenience method called `config`, unaware of its reserved status, and without any issues until `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def config
  Rails.configuration.general
end

# Ruby 3 end-less method style
def config() = Rails.configuration.general
```

Oddly enough, I can't find any source documentation, just [reserved words](https://gist.github.com/antonfefilov/14b1eaf740b02cba8be0) maintained by individuals. This one is on me though, really shouldn't be putting non-RESTful non-protected methods like this in the first place. There is actually a [note](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0c530467e6506d633090d6c9e9614b8fc65dc800#diff-7cca3eec1b3bb1724cff0a6562c5f8ca07c55b1edeb8432055ecdb85d9b4a382R70) warning about this in the guides.